# Resolving gem dependencies while installing rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubygems

You Requested eventmachine=1.0.0

The bundle is currently has event machine locked at 0.12.10
try running bundle update environment.
After that it's showing problem in image.

[image]
after applying command "gem install kgio -v '2.6.0' " showing like this in image.
[image]

I followed the instruction and gone thorough the path gem_make.out file. 
which contains the 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your dependencies are "CLASHING" with different gems try using the source of one or more of the gems.

Example:

```
gem 'capybara', git: 'https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara.git'

gem 'eventmachine', git: 'https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine.git'
```

Comment: Thanks for you help..will try and let you know.